# How to enable location layer by hiding blue dot on google map v2 0r How to replace blue dot by my marker on location enable

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

when I used LocationManager class and want to change location within 1 meter and 1 millisecond. I have seen Current location not exactly getting like in built map in android device. And when i Enabled currentlocation on goggle map V2 than enable blue dot and This shows current location. But it change location by jump and i want to animate marker.
any help :

googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);

Answer (score 1):

Are you using [LocationListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener.html)

LocationListener is used for receiving notifications from the FusedLocationProviderApi when the location has changed. The methods are called if the LocationListener has been registered with the location client using the requestLocationUpdates(GoogleApiClient, LocationRequest, LocationListener) or requestLocationUpdates(GoogleApiClient, LocationRequest, LocationListener, Looper) methods.

Public Methods

public abstract void onLocationChanged (Location location)

```
   Called when the location has changed.
```

Parameters
location    The updated location.